# Find amicable pair numbers of the from $m = 2^{k}a, n = 2^{k}bc$, where $k < 35$ and a, b, c are odd primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I used computer program to generate numbers of this form, then verify if they are amicable. However, it took too long to finish, is there any special technique to verify if a pair is amicable?

One pair that I found is $m = 284 = 2^{2}.71, n = 220 = 2^{2}.5.11$

Thanks,
Chan

Comment: Did you read the wikipedia article? There is a method for generating such numbers there.

      http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amicable_number

Comment: @milcak: Thanks for the link. I created a table of first 10,000 odd primes, but it's not practical. Since C(10000, 3) is a really big number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a nice program for finding amicable pairs, there is a related question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218056/how-to-optimize-code-for-finding-amicable-pairs).

[Here](http://tutoree7.pastebin.com/wKvMAWpT) is a code from this question. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It did help ;)

Answer (score 1):

See also Amicable pairs, a survey
http://oai.cwi.nl/oai/asset/4143/04143D.pdf
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by Euler who generalized a rule of Thabit ibn Kurrah, see [Breeding Amicable Pairs in Abundance](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1986-46-173/S0025-5718-1986-0815849-1/S0025-5718-1986-0815849-1.pdf) by Borho and Hoffmann for some history.  To compute pairs using Euler's rule, choose an integer $0 < j < k$ and let $g$ be $2^{k-j}+1$ and let $b=2^kg-1$, $c=2^jg-1$ and $a=(b+1)(c+1) - 1$. If $a$,$b$ and $c$ are all prime then $m$ and $n$ form an amicable pair, and all such pairs are of this form.

To derive this you plug $m=2^k a$ and $n=2^k bc$ into the definition of an amicable pair you get three equalities that reduce to a quadratic Diophantine equation (ellipse) in two variables.  The problem is solved with somewhat more generality in [Amicable numbers and the Bilinear Diophantine Equation](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1968-22-101/S0025-5718-1968-0224543-9/S0025-5718-1968-0224543-9.pdf) by Lee.  Many (most?) [known amicable pairs](http://amicable.homepage.dk/knwnc2.htm) were derived by some variation of Lee's method (presumably known to Euler).

For this particular problem we have
$$ (2^{k+1}-1)(a+1) = (2^{k+1}-1)(b+1)(c+1) = 2^k(a+bc)$$
so $a=(b+1)(c+1)-1$  Substituting, we get
$$(2^{k+1}-1)(b+1)(c+1) = 2^k((b+1)(c+1) + bc -1) $$
after some algebra
$$bc - (2^k-1)(b+c) = 2^{k+1}-1$$
or
$$(b-(2^k-1))(c-(2^k-1))=2^{k+1}-1 + (2^k-1)^2 = 2^{2k}$$
as both $(b-(2^k-1))$ and $(c-(2^k-1))$ are integers that divide $2^{2k}$ they must be of the form $2^j$ and $2^{2k-j}$.  So if $b=2^k+2^j-1$ and $c=2^{2k-j}+2^k-1$ as well as $a=(b+1)(c+1)-1$ are all prime, then $(2^ka,2^kbc)$ is an amicable pair, and all such pairs of this form are found by this method.

Here is some python which solves your problem quickly

```
import sympy
#for primality test

#test 2^x + 2^y - 1 for primality
def goodpair(x,y):
    return sympy.ntheory.isprime(2**x + 2**y - 1)

# j,k pairs giving prime b
bset=set([])

# j,k pairs giving prime c
cset=set([])

#find primes of the form 2^x + 2^y - 1 and store possibilities for b and c
for x in range(1, 70):
    for y in range(x, 71):
        if goodpair(x, y):
            bset.add((x, y))
            if 2 * x > y:
                cset.add((2*x-y,x))

#for cases where both b and c are prime test a = (b+1)(c+1)-1
# for primality, and output pair
for j,k in bset.intersection(cset):
    b = 2**k + 2**j -1
    c = 2**(2 * k - j) + 2**k - 1
    if sympy.ntheory.isprime((b+1)*(c+1)-1):
        print j,k,2**k*((b+1)*(c+1)-1),2**k*b*c
```